# error on reference to return value

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

This code can't pass compiling. The only difference is the return type. Foo1's return type is the user-defined struct and Foo2's is int.

```
struct test
{    
};    

test Foo1()  
{  
    return test();  
}  

int Foo2()  
{  
    return 0;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    test& r1 = Foo1(); //ok  
    int& r2 = Foo2(); //no but why? Is it the C++ standard way?  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: For me compiling on g++-4.7 neither line is okay

Comment: clang++: `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'test' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'test'`, same error on both lines. What's your compiler?

Comment: Both lines are wrong: you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

Comment: Why exactly do you want it to be a reference? What you are trying to do doesn't seem to make sense conceptually.

Comment: MSVC++ can pass "test& r1 = Foo1();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a reference you can still use a reference to const otherwise neither of the line will compile :

```
struct test
{
};

test Foo1()
{
    return test();
}

int Foo2()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const test& r1 = Foo1(); // ok now
    const int& r2 = Foo2();  //ok now

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is either a compiler bug or its "language extension" (for example MS VC++ has many such "language extensions"). In both cases of the function calls the compiler shall issue an error because it may not bind a temporary object to non-const reference.